# Embedding website into an cordova/ionic tab and retrieving data

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, hybrid-mobile-app, embedding

tl;dr:

- Embed/show website into an app with a hybrid framework like cordova/ionic
- Get data from website
- Create local push notifications with recieved data
- Take pictures and post to instagram (if available)
- **Is there a better solution for this than cordova/ionic?**

Hey there,

I’m currently developing an ionic app (tabs), one of them should embed one of our companies webpages, the other tabs should (for example) allow the user to create local push notifications (might also be solved as a modal); things that relates to what the user did on the webpage (**so the app needs to get data from the website**).

The layout could look similar to the facebook app, the footer with tabs on the bottom and the website/content embedded above.

Now to my problem:
The inAppBrowser Plugin seems not to be designed to solve this kind of task, as it always opens a new window or redirects to a native browser, and using an iFrame might be a solution, but I’m not sure if it’s the best for this kind of problem, especially with the problem of recieving data from the website (e.g. if a button is clicked and the associated content).

**How could I solve this in an elegant way, or is there a better approach than using cordova/ionic?**

Thanks in advance!